# How to close popup using Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I've been trying to close a popup that shows up when opening a link.

I've tried clicking the close button on the popup using the Xpath but the code keeps opening a new page, apparently clicking the wrong link or so.

Here's the code I'm trying.

```
Public Sub scrapeCIL2()
    Dim bot As New WebDriver, btn As Object, i As Long, pageCount As Long

    Dim wins As Variant



    bot.Start "chrome", "https://duproprio.com/en/search/list?search=true&amp;regions%5B0%5D=6&amp;is_for_sale=1&amp;with_builders=1&amp;parent=1&amp;pageNumber=2&amp;sort=-published_at"
    bot.Get "/"
    pageCount = bot.FindElementsByClass("pagination__item").Count
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")


    'To click the close button of the popup
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='react-component-InfoSessionsPopup']/div/div/div[1]").Click


    bot.Quit

End Sub
```

Any help to close this popup using Selenium VBA will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To close the popup that shows up when opening the [link](https://duproprio.com/en/search/list?search=true&regions%5B0%5D=6&is_for_sale=1&with_builders=1&parent=1&pageNumber=2&sort=-published_at) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `FindElementByCss()`:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("div.webinar-popup__close").Click
  ```
- Using `FindElementByXPath()`:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='webinar-popup__close']").Click
  ```

Comment: Rather than close the popup, it's opening a new tab

Answer (score 0):

I'd wait until the javascript is fully loaded by Selenium, then use a macro or RPA tool like Approbotic to click on the close button by using the X/Y screen coordinates. Something like this should work for you:

```
Public Sub scrapeCIL2()
    Dim bot As New WebDriver, btn As Object, i As Long, pageCount As Long
    Set x = CreateObject("AppRobotic.API")
    Dim wins As Variant



    bot.Start "chrome", "https://duproprio.com/en/search/list?search=true&amp;regions%5B0%5D=6&amp;is_for_sale=1&amp;with_builders=1&amp;parent=1&amp;pageNumber=2&amp;sort=-published_at"
    bot.Get "/"
    pageCount = bot.FindElementsByClass("pagination__item").Count
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")


    'To click the close button of the popup
    'bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='react-component-InfoSessionsPopup']/div/div/div[1]").Click
    'Move the mouse to X/Y coordinates after looking up popup coordinates with UI Item Explorer
    Call x.MoveCursor(500,500) :
    'Wait one second
    x.Wait(1000) :
    'Click the popup close button
    x.MouseLeftClick() :

    bot.Quit

End Sub
```